# Rational cohomological dimension of a locally finite group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, group-cohomology

$\DeclareMathOperator\cd{cd}$Recall that the **rational cohomological dimension** of a group $G$ is the supremum of the set of integers $k$ such that there exists a $\mathbb{Q}[G]$-module $M$ with $H^k(G;M) \neq 0$.  Denote this by $\cd_{\mathbb{Q}}(G)$.

If $G$ is a finite group, then it is easy to see that $\cd_{\mathbb{Q}}(G) = 0$.

However, it is not clear to me what the rational cohomological dimension of a locally finite group is (where "locally finite" means that all finitely generated subgroups are finite).  Since homology commutes with direct limits, the rational **homological** dimension of these group are $0$.

So my question is what can be said about the rational cohomological dimension of a locally finite group $G$.  I mostly care about countable $G$.  In fact, the easiest example where I don't know the answer is
$$G = \bigoplus_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited version.** If $G$ is a countable infinite locally finite group, then the rational cohomological dimension is exactly $1$.  The rational cohomological dimension for an infinite group is never $0$ because if $\mathbb Q$ is a projective $\mathbb QG$-module, then you need an idempotent $e$ with $\mathbb QGe\cong \mathbb Q$ and that is impossible unless $G$ is finite and $e$ is the average of all elements of $G$.

Here are two proofs that the projective dimesion of $\mathbb QG$ is at most one for a countable locally finite group.  This amounts to showing the augmentation ideal is projective.  Then $\mathbb Q$ has projective dimension at most $1$ since $I\to \mathbb QG\to \mathbb Q\to 0$ is a projective resolution where $I$ is the augmentation ideal.

It follows from a result in Dicks book Groups, trees and projective modules (1980)  characterizing projectivity of the augmentation ideal of $RG$ that $\mathbb QG$ has a projective augmentation ideal whenever $G$ is countable and locally finite.   See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297043/using-dunwoodys-results-on-cohomological-dimension-to-learn-about-a-von-neumann?rq=1) for more details.

The second argument is that by a result of Connell, $\mathbb QG$ is von Neumann regular if $G$ is locally finite.  The augmentation ideal is countably generated as a left ideal if $G$ is countable and hence by a result of Kaplansky is projective (Kaplansky proved that a countably generated left ideal in a von Neumann regular ring is projective).

Thus for a countably infinite locally finite group the rational cohomological dimension is one.

It follows from Theorem 2 of [Derek Holt's 1981 paper (DOI link)](https://doi.org/10.1112/blms/13.6.557) that if $G$ is a locally finite group of cardinality $\aleph_1$, then the rational cohomological dimension of $G$ is at least $2$.

Comment: There's one thing I know making a big difference between countable and uncountable locally finite groups: $H^1(G,\mathbf{Z}G)$ is infinite when $G$ is infinite countable locally finite, while it's zero for $G$ locally finite uncountable. This former (easy) fact is due to Scott-Sonneborn; the latter is due du Holt.

Comment: @YCor, he shows H^2 is not zero when G is uncountable

Comment: Browsing subsequent papers (see other papers by Holt in 1981 and those quoting him, etc), there seems to be a few more papers on this, but I'm not sure what they exactly conjecture or say (as it doesn't only focus on rational cd, and also because some make set-theoretic assumptions). Does it conjecture that a locally finite group of cardinal $\aleph_n$ has rational cohomological dimension $n$, and infinite when $n\ge\aleph_0$? Is part of the conjecture known (e.g., is it known that the cohomological dimension is $\ge n$? is it known for abelian groups? etc.

Comment: @YCor,  in Derek's paper or seemed to conjecture at least n.  Maybe Derek will chime in.